# facebook like button language choice by location

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

Seems to me it is legal and possible to create a Facebook Like button that displays like (en-US) or Gefallt mir (de-DE) text depending on the location of the user.
I'm trying to generate the Facebook like button using Facebook link: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Unfortunately, as result it contains

```
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

or

```
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

As you see, I choose the language automatically.

How to solve this question so that person from Germany sees a German Facebook like button, and the person from the US sees an English one ("Like").

Comment: Ask someone to see how it displays. Have you checked?